# How can you use a Python library with CircuitPython?

Tags: python, package, adafruit-circuitpython

I recently got started using CircuitPython on microcontrollers (specifially the Raspberry Pi Pico W and Zero W [I know, technically it's a single-board computer]). There are some Python packages that I would like to use on the microcontroller, but I don't know how to do it. The [documentation](https://learn.adafruit.com/welcome-to-circuitpython/circuitpython-libraries) says you can use the `lib` folder to install packages, so I tried downloading the package from https://pypi.org/ but I wasn't sure what to add to the folder. Then, I found out about [circup](https://github.com/adafruit/circup) which I thought could solve my problem, but it turns out it only works with official Adafruit libraries. So, how can I install other libraries to the microcontroller to use with CircuitPython?

Thanks in advance.